# CasperJS, Code does not work?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Iam new with Javascript(since yesterday) and i really dont know, why my script does not work.
I try do login to this Website, with multiple Data out of a .txt file.
They are in File like:
id:pw(/n)id:pw(/n)... and so on

```
function login(MYID,MYPW){

            var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
            var url = 'http://leya2.eu/';

            var casper = require('casper').create({
                verbose: false,
                logLevel: 'debug'
            });
            phantom.casperTest = true;
            casper.test.comment('Start');

            casper.start(url, function() {  
            this.waitForSelector("leya2.jpg",
                function pass () {
                },
                function fail () {
                },
                20000
            );

            casper.then(function() {
            this.sendKeys('input[name=userid]', 'Dantes999');
            this.sendKeys('input[name=userpass]', '123456789');
            this.click('input[value="LOGIN"]')
            });

            casper.then(function() {    
                this.fill('form[class="login"]', {
                  'userid': 'Dantes999',
                  'userpass': '123456789'
                }, true);
            });

            casper.then(function() {
                //console.log(this.getPageContent());
            });

            });

            casper.run(function() {
                this.echo('done');
            return 
                this.exit();
            });
}



var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.open('acc_all.txt', 'r');

while(!stream.atEnd()) {
    var line = stream.readLine();
    console.log(line);
var id = str.substring(0,":");   
var pw = str.substring(":",end);  

var a = login(function() {id},{pw});
}
stream.close();
```

Error message is like missing }

Comment: where are you calling "login()"? aren't you just assign a variable with "var a = login(function() {id},{pw});"`?

Comment: so a should return some data ? something like, login sucessfull or not... hmm

i think best way is..
1. load website
2. get login data
3. login
4. success ?(seach for field "logout") else fail
5. notice if fail or not

but idk why at the moment it does not work =/

Compiler: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'